# How do I print the last values of an ArrayList that aren't part of a successive sequence of four values?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a beginner in Java. I was wondering how I would print the last couple of values for this reverse arrayList since they are not part of a successive sequence of 4. I was thinking of using if `(numbers.size()%4==0)` but I dont know where to properly implement it.

---

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class printArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Integer> numbers= new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(10);
        numbers.add(13);
        numbers.add(2);
        numbers.add(8);
        numbers.add(7);
        numbers.add(90);
        numbers.add(-1);
        numbers.add(2);
        numbers.add(4);
        numbers.add(5);




        System.out.println(numbers);

        System.out.println(reverse4(numbers));

    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> reverse4 (ArrayList<Integer> numbers){
        ArrayList< Integer> reverseSet= new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i += 4) {//goes from 0 to 4, 4 to 8 and keeps incrementing by 4
                for (int k = i + 3; k >= i ; k--)// reverse order, executes 4 times before going to the outer loop
             reverseSet.add(numbers.get(k));


        }

        return reverseSet;  

    }
}
```

Comment: How many last  elements of `reverseSet` do you want to print?

Comment: Yea, but I also want to print the last values unchanged. For example, if I have an array of values 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 the first 4 successive values reversed will be 4  3 2 1 and the rest would print out unchanged. So it would look like this at the end: 4 3 2 1 5 6 7.

Comment: Depends on the size of the the arrayList. If there is 23 elements then there would be 3 that are unchanged since they are not a multiple nor part of a sequence of 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if `k` is within range

```
if (k < numbers.size())
```

before you do the `reverseSet.add()`.

**Edit:** sorry, misunderstood what you're doing. You want to reverse any full sets of four, but not any partial sets at the end, it sounds like.

So, count:

```
position |   1      2      3      4   |  5      6      7
---------+----------------------------+--------------------
count    | size-7 size-6 size-5 size-4|size-3 size-2 size-1
            last
            one

position |   1      2      3      4   |  5      6
---------+----------------------------+--------------------
count    | size-6 size-5 size-4 size-3|size-2 size-1
            last
            one

position |   1      2      3      4   |  5
---------+----------------------------+--------------------
count    | size-5 size-4 size-3 size-2|size-1
            last
            one

position |   1      2      3      4   |
---------+----------------------------+--------------------
count    | size-4 size-3 size-2 size-1|
            last
            one
```

It looks like the last valid value of `i` should always be less than the size of the array minus three (unless the ArrayList is too short, but you'd need different code for that—my previous answer should work there). So instead of what I said above, replace `i < numbers.size()` with **`i < numbers.size() - 3`**.

Comment: This is my result:  Original  [10, 13, 2, 8, 7, 90, -1, 2, 4, 5]
Reversed [8, 2, 13, 10, 2, -1, 90, 7, 5, 4] How would I get 4 and 5 to remain unchanged since they are not part of a sequence of 4?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the changed `reverse4` method :

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> reverse4(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
        ArrayList<Integer> reverseSet = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i += 4) {
            if (i + 3 < numbers.size()) { // check if remaining number of elements less than 4
                for (int k = i + 3; k >= i; k--)
                    reverseSet.add(numbers.get(k));

            } else {
                for (int k = i; k < numbers.size(); k++) {
                    reverseSet.add(numbers.get(k));   // add the remaining elements without reversing
                }
            }
        }

        return reverseSet;

    }
```

Note the new conditions to check if the list has 4 remaining elements.